# What is the best option to store session data in express js

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I need to implement session in express js based API. I have only these three options to store session data.

1. Couchbase
2. Mongo DB
3. SQL Server DB

I read few articles online which suggest "redis" or "Memcached" are good options to store session data. But I don't have option to set any of these two store.

Which option should I select out of three for a production application?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the file store option, easiest to implement (IMO)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store

```
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new FileStore(options),
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```